# ActiveMQ Producer resend if destination not available

Tags: java, activemq-classic, failover

I am using the latest ActiveMQ with persistence and I have implemented already the producer and consumer which are working as intended. However I cannot get to producer to resend messages when the consumer is back from downtime. It only starts sending messages produces after the consumer is back up.

**Producer**

```
private void someInitFunction(){      
    connection = factory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

    producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
    }

private void onNewMessage(Serialized data){
    try{
        ObjectMessage message = createObjectMessage();
        message.setObject(data);
        producer.send(message);
       } catch(Exception e){ log.error("consumer not available");}
}
```

What I want to achieve is to make the producer re-send the messages that failed to deliver while the consumer is down. So as an example: producer sends message 1,2 and consumer receives them but then it goes offline. Producer sends 3,4 while consumer is offline and the messages should be stored until consumer becomes available and 3,4 are resent for the consumer to receive.

I have read http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html and enabled durable queue using `DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT` but messages are not resent on-reconnect.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: To be clear: the consumer does not have to be available - only the broker. The broker will automatically deliver the messages once the consumer comes online. You need to handle resend (if broker is down) manually (loop or whatever suits your app)

Comment: Perfect. Now everything is clear. The problem in my design is that the broker and consumer are on the same machine, producer loosing connection while the app is unreachable due to various reasons. Thank you for the valuable input @Petter